# How to set a different content-type for each FormData entry with Dio?

Tags: flutter, dart, multipart, dio

I am trying to upload an image and some extra data (JSON map) with the Dio post request. My question is how can I set content-type for each field of `FormData.fromMap`

```dart
final data = FormData.fromMap({
        "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          path,
          filename:name,
        ),
        "mapData": {"name": "user_name"},  //I wnat to set content-type for this value
      });
```

How to add content-type for each FormData entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add JSON data we can do it with `MultipartFile.fromString` where we can specify the `content-type` of the data.

import `http_parser` package form `'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';` to use `MediaType` class.

```dart
 final data = FormData.fromMap({
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      path,
      filename: name,
    ),
    "mapData": await MultipartFile.fromString(
      {"name": "user_name"},
      contentType: MediaType.parse('application/json'),
    ),
  },
 ListFormat.multiCompatible,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to json encode the data before sending it too, here:

```
final data = FormData.fromMap({
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      path,
      filename: name,
    ),
    "mapData": MultipartFile.fromString(
      jsonEncode({"name": "user_name"}),
      contentType: MediaType.parse('application/json'),
    ),
  },
);
```